# If statement within FileSystemWatcher Not working in Powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, events, filesystemwatcher, scriptblock

I am trying to implement a `FileSystemWatcher` that contains an `if` statement that evaluates and argument passed to it, but it doesn't seem to be evaluating. Am I making a mistake? Here is the code:

```bsh
Function Auto-Watcher
{
    param ($folder, $filter, $Program)

    $watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
        IncludeSubdirectories = $true
        EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    }

    Write-Host "Watching $folder for creation or moving of $filter files..."

    $changeAction = {
        $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

        if ($Program -match "Report1") {
            Write-Host $Path "Ready for Report1 Generation"
            else {
                if ($Program -match "Report2") {
                    Write-Host Split-Path $Path "Ready for Report2 Generation"
                    else {
                        write-output "Error, not capable of matching identical strings"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Write-Host "The file $name was $changeType at $timeStamp"
    }
    Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher -EventName "Created" -Action $changeAction
}
```

I added in a `Write-Output` statement before the `if` statements that confirmed that `$Program -match "Report1"` was returning `$true`, but nothing in the `if` statements seems to be evaluated. What can I do?

Comment: You're calling the `Auto-Watcher` function somewhere, right?  Even so, it still might be problematic that the lifetime/scope of `$watcher` is that function.  Does `Write-Host "The file $name was $changeType at $timeStamp"` get executed?

Comment: Yes and yes it does.

Comment: Your `if`/`else` structure is incorrect inside of `$changeAction`.  Both `else` blocks seem to be _inside_ what should be their associated `if` block.  That is, you have `if (...) { else { } }` when it should be `if (...) { } else { }`.

Comment: @Bacon I'm surprised it doesnt throw error on else without an if. All of these if else statements are like that.

Comment: @Jawad It does at the command line.  Running `if ($true) { else { } }` throws `else : The term 'else' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`  In the question, though, it'd be up to the code inside `FileSystemWatcher` that raises the `Created` event to handle that exception, although I'm not altogether sure how that gets propagated when a .NET event calls a PowerShell `ScriptBlock` event handler.

Comment: Another problem with your code: only a `$Program` variable defined in the _global_ scope will be seen inside your `-Action` script block. As shown, the function-local `$Program` parameter variable would _not_ be seen. To robustly pass values to your `-Action` script block, use `Register-ObjectEvent`'s `-MessageData` parameter; inside the action script block, use `$Event.MessageData` to access the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if`/`else` structure is incorrect inside of `$changeAction`.  Both `else` blocks are *inside* what should be their associated `if` block.  That is, you have this...

```bsh
if ($condition) {
    else {
    }
}
```

...when it should be this...

```bsh
if ($condition) {
    # $true branch
} else {
    # $false branch
}
```

Try defining the `if` structure within `$changeAction` like this...

```bsh
if ($Program -match "Report1") {
    Write-Host $Path "Ready for Report1 Generation"
} elseif ($Program -match "Report2") {
    Write-Host (Split-Path $Path) "Ready for Report2 Generation"
} else {
    Write-Output "Error, not capable of matching identical strings"
}
```

...and see if that works.  Note that I added `()` around the call to `Split-Path $Path` so that is evaluated and the result passed to `Write-Host`.

You could also rewrite the above using a `switch` statement...

```bsh
switch -Regex ($Program) {
    "Report1" {
        Write-Host $Path "Ready for Report1 Generation"
        break
    }
    "Report2" {
        Write-Host (Split-Path $Path) "Ready for Report2 Generation"
        break
    }
    Default {
        Write-Output "Error, not capable of matching identical strings"
        break
    }
}
```

I added the `-Regex` parameter to make it equivalent to your use of the `-match` operator in the `if` conditions.  Note that if your intent was to perform an exact string comparison in the `if` statements you could use, for example, `if ($Program -eq "Report1") {` to perform a case-insensitive comparison.  If your intent was to perform a substring comparison you could use `if ($Program -like "*Report1*") {` instead of the `-match` operator.